# Angular Material: Manpulating ng-model value in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

here is my view

```
<content class="md-whiteframe-5dp" layout-padding>
        <div layout="row">
            <md-input-container flex="33">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input ng-model="firstname" type="text"/>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container flex="33">
                <label>Middle Name</label>
                <input ng-model="middlename"  type="text"/>
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container flex="33">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input ng-model="lastname"  type="text"/>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>

        <div layout="row">
            <md-input-container flex="66">
                <label>User Name</label>
                <input ng-model="username"  type="hidden" />
                {{firstname}}.{{lastname}}
            </md-input-container>
            </div>
```

The model `username` should be generated as a concatenated string of first three characters of models `firstname` and `lastname`. Means username of *Abraham Lincoln* should be *abrlin*. And at the same, onblur of lastname the username should be shown.

As per the above code when i write `{{firstname}}.{{lastname}}` its okay, but generating the substring is something i am looking for.

i tried below code which didn't work

```
angular.module("customerModule", ['ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial'])
       .controller('AppCtrl',
       function ($scope) {
           $scope.username = $scope.firstname.substring(0, 3) + "." + $scope.lastname.substring(0, 3);
       }
    );

function getSubStr(stringValue, stringLen) {
    return stringValue.substring(0, stringLen);
}
```

How should the requirement be taken up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is ***no need*** to make another function `substring()`, It should be like this

```
$scope.username = $scope.firstname.substr(0, 3) + $scope.lastname.substring(0, 3);
```

`substr()` is an inbuilt function provided by Javascript. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).